# Using Gravity Forms Conditional Logic to Run a Popup Script (Do I Even Need to Use Conditional Logic?)

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, popup, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to create a popup that triggers if a certain range of selections within a dropdown field are selected.

The dropdown is of years from 1900 to 2017. When someone selects anything before 1970 a popup alert should show up. So with Gravity Forms' conditional logic I can trigger a pre-written line of HTML if anything before 1970 shows up.

But I'm not sure how to code the line of HTML so that it triggers a popup automatically. Right now I have some popups in place that are triggered based on "onclick". But obviously, going that route, the conditional logic only presents a button that has to be clicked for a popup to show. And I need the popup to happen automatically.

Maybe there's a solution that doesn't even need to use Gravity Form's conditional logic?

Thanks!